# Django User Management Add, Disable and choose Group

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm looking for a django app that would allow superusers to add, update, disable users, and to choose which group would this user belong to.

I have looked at different solutions:

1. Creating another admin site, with only user management registered to it.
2. django-user-accounts
3. django-userena

Those offer's very good solutions, but I'm looking for a simple interface for my users so I can't add another admin site.

I'm looking for simple create user, disable user function from the font-end of the system.

I suppose I can just go ahead and code this one but I wanted to check if there is any app that is available first.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'm looking for a django app that does user management, add, disable, and choose group permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further reference so those who come across this post can benefit, I have searched for more than a week for a simple, and quick user management app.

There are two notable solutions advanced solutions first [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts) it handles:

1. User activation
2. Forget Password
3. Sign up
4. Email confirmation
5. Signup tokens for private betas
6. Password reset
7. Account management (update account settings and change password)
8. Account deletion

second notable solution is [django-userarena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) it handles

1. signup
2. signin
3. account editing
4. privacy settings
5. private messaging

having a back-office solution that only administrators are offered the ability to create a user, enable/disable them. I was only left with the solution of creating my own code, which is not bad, but I was hoping to find an easy, and tested solution.

Maybe if somebody is interested I can upload it someday.

Thanks